# Did the Apollo astronauts do any EVAs in mid-flight?

Tags: the-moon, nasa, apollo-program, eva

For example on their way to the Moon, did the astronauts also leave the Apollo CSM during their flight? Or did they go outside only on the Moon? Were or could there have been any EVAs in mid-flight of the Apollo spacecraft? If no, why not?

Comment: Good question, but one that already has an answer ;)